# Adding a script with onload in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm building a plugin for ecommerce stores that need to include my js resource, which needs to execute and `init()` function `onload` which creates a `window.onmessage` listener. Normally, a script like this would be added in the `head` section of :

```
<script async type='text/javascript' src='/static/my_resource.js onload='init()'></script>
```

I've build a demo store with `Next.js` and am trying to add the script tag like so:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

...

<Head>
        <title>Demo store</title>
        <script async type='text/javascript' src='/static/my_resource.js onLoad='init()'></script>
</Head>
```

But `Next.js` complains that `onLoad` cannot accept a string. Obviously, the `init()` function will only become available once the resource has loaded. How to do this correctly in `Next.js`?

Comment: If you're using next 11, you can use the script component - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#executing-code-after-loading-onload. If not, you can still use onLoad but like the error says, it doesn't accept a string - you need to pass it a function.

Comment: Well... that's why I posted the question. The function is not available until the resource has loaded, so I cannot reference it at the time of writing the script tag. Simple html allows for such deferred calling of a function, so I just want to understand how to do it in Next.js.

Comment: I guess the `init()` function gets loaded globally then? You could try calling it with `window.init()`.

Comment: It's strange, even when I do `onLoad={() => console.log('LOADED')}`, I don't get this logged to console... However, when I call `init()` or `window.init()` (both work) inside a `useEffect` hook, they both work. So... how come doesn't the `onLoad` property do anything?

Comment: So, it appears `onLoad` works with Next 11's `Script` component as expected, but not with `<Head><script /><Head>` for some reason...